# Как разместить один rtf-файл в несколько RichTextBox

Tags: c#, rtf

Имеется rtf-файл. Необходимо открыть его и каждую страницу записать в свой `richtextbox`. Требуется записывать именно в richtextbox.rtf, чтобы форматирование и все таблицы сохранились. Каким образом возможно это реализовать?

upd. Сделал следующим образом:
Открыл rtf-файл во временный richtextbox, записал в строковую переменную str = richtextbox.rtf, после richtextbox.text = str. и дальше по тексту искал разрыв страницы (в rtf разрыв страницы "\page"), копировал шапку rtf в котором указываются шрифт, размер шрифта и тд, и добавлял то, что между разрывами, далее присваивал полученную строку в нужный richtextbox.rtf

Comment: А что вы пробовали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете загрузить rtf в оффлайновый `FlowDocument`, и вытащить из него куски. Например, так:

```
var document = new FlowDocument();

TextRange txtRange = new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd);

using (var stream = File.OpenRead(@"D:\simple.rtf"))
    txtRange.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
```

Имея `FlowDocument`, вы можете разбить его на куски согласно своей логике. После разбиения, каждый из кусков можно легко вставить в другой `FlowDocument` таким путём:

```
void CloneContent(TextRange from, TextRange to)
{
    using (var s = new MemoryStream())
    {
        from.Save(s, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
        to.Load(s, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
    }
}

void CopyInto(FlowDocument d, TextRange source)
{
    CloneContent(source, new TextRange(d.ContentStart, d.ContentEnd));
}
```

Comment: а как разбить document на страницы,  в конце каждой страницы rtf файла присутствует разрыв страницы, нет опыта работы с FlowDocunent, читаю не могу разобраться.
 в данный момент я загружаю rtf  файл в richtextbox1, а от туда копирую текст по остальным, таким способов форматирование и  таблицы пропадают.

Comment: Ну, вы можете сканировать контент и искать разрыв страницы, по идее. Я попробую найти, как кодируется разрыв страницы, пока не могу. Гляньте и вы тоже.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!